# Setting \setcounter{tocdepth} for an individual chapter

Tags: table-of-contents, counters

Hiya,
Is it possible to set the `\setcounter{tocdepth}{..}` for one chapter only?

The default depth is fine for the entire document, except for the last chapter- I only want the chapter title to appear in the table of contents (all sections, subsections etc should not appear).

I could adjust all of my sections to use an asterisk, eg `\section*{...}` which will cause them to not be numbered and not show up in the ToC, however I want these sections to be numbered! (I have references to these numbers elsewhere).

I have tried placing `\setcounter{tocdepth}{1}` to the chapter I want this to apply to, and have tried adding it to my main tex file before the `\include` of that chapter, doesn't seem to work (I guess because `\maketitle` has already been called by that stage?)

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

If I understand you right, the code below should do what you want.

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,english]{report}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}
  \tableofcontents

  \blinddocument

  \addtocontents{toc}{\protect\setcounter{tocdepth}{0}}
  \blinddocument
\end{document}
```

Setting the counter `tocdepth` to »1« would also show the sections.

One should note that this will change the `tocdepth` for the rest of the document. Simply using the same command you can set the depth to what ever you wish for following chapters.

Comment: Damn. I missed posting this answer by a few seconds. I think you need 1 to see sections and 2 for subsections, at least in the book class.

Comment: It would also help the relatively uninitiated that the `\blindtext` package and the `\blinddocument` commands are just for generating dummy, testing texts. They are not part of the solution.

Comment: Thanks, that works perfectly. And thanks also Willie Wong, that would have been pretty confusing figuring out why all my content suddenly changed... :p